# Drag and Drop the Canvas around the browser screen

Tags: javascript, canvas, raphael, drag

I'm new to Raphael as well as to JS..  I need to be able to drag the Canvas itself, not the object in it, to various locations on the screen.  I looked everywhere on the web and can't find a clue.  Of course, the user would have to try and grab the canvas at some free spot ... free from child objects...

Any clue would be greatly appreciated.

Here is how I constructed the Canvas on this site:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
    <title>Raphael Play</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/raphael.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/mood.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css">  
            #canvas_container {  
            position:absolute;
                width: 803;  
            left:200px; 
            top:100px;
            border: 0px solid #555;  
            -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 84px #999; 
            -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 84px #999; 
            box-shadow: 0px 0px 84px #000; 
            border-radius: 20px 20px 20px 20px;
            background-color:#fff;
            background-image:url(static/VAZZZ.png);
            }  
     </style>
  </head>
  <body>
      <div id="canvas_container" ></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a cross-browser drag function and event listener for the `<div>`.

http://jsfiddle.net/MtbJe/

- Your CSS was incomplete (no height specified and width was missing "px").
- The box-shadow significantly reduces the smoothness of the dragging, you may actually want to use an image in this instance (remove the box-shadow to see how much smoother it is).
- If you want to make something else in the UI be the actual drag handler (but still move the entire `<div>`) you will have to change the event listener to be for that element and change the 15th line of the JavaScript from:

  ```
  var dragObj = e.target ? e.target : e.srcElement;
  ```

  to something like:

  ```
  var dragObj = e.target ? e.target.parentNode : e.srcElement.parentNode;
  ```

I've had this code saved for many years and I believe the original author is http://www.quirksmode.org/ though I don't see it there anymore. You will find a lot of great information about JS on this site. Again, this is a cross-browser script which I'm not sure you need given you are using canvas. If you are very new to JS and working with the DOM, then I'm sure the code will look a bit confusing and I encourage you to ask additional questions.

Comment: Wow, Sameera, you really know your stuff!

Comment: But I'm not able to get it to work.  I placed the JS code you supplied between script tags in the header.  As you suspect, I'm totally new to JS!

Comment: I see that in Fiddle, if you catch the canvas close to the edge, the canvas drops out. You suggested using a child to drag the parent. I've seen this problem in FoxPro.  The child follows the mouse faster than the form and the parent never drops out.  So kudos to you for anticipating that.  I'm impressed.

Comment: Somehow I got a ghost of the canvas to follow the mouse, but when I drop it in another location the ghost disappears and no movement of the canvas has taken place.

Comment: Dennis -- a browser parses your HTML document top-to-bottom. This means that with this code in your <head> tag, an error will be thrown. This is because the code is looking for the element canvas_container, but this element hasn't been created yet! (it's created later on in the HTML). Two ways I would recommend fixing this are: 1) put this code in a <script> tag at the bottom of your page (just before the </body> close tag), or 2) create a window.onload function and place the first part of the code (not the drag function) in it, and it will execute when the page (and element) is ready.

Comment: Yes, you are right!  I tried that just before I saw your reply.  I'm just a novice in JS...  about 2 days into it...ha ha ha.  Thank you kindly.  It works just great!  A lot for me to think about in that code.  So different from VFP...